# Setting variable to @Published breaks the code without any errors

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm learning Swift, and trying to make a first app - Tic Tac Toe. I want to implement both PVP and AI, and stuck on displaying who's next to move (X/O). AI mode (just random for now) works well, and PVP as well, but it always displays "X to move". If I set a variable `playerToMove` to `@Published` in TicTacToe file, so text can update, app doesn't work. Content view shows everything, but I cannot click anything. If I build the app, it's just a white screen.

Here I'm displaying the text that should be updated:

```
struct ContentView: View {
@ObservedObject var ticTacToe = TicTacToeModel()

var currPlayer: String {
    return self.ticTacToe.playerToMove == false ? "X" : "O"
}

var body: some View {
    Text(self.selection == true ? "\(currPlayer) to move" : " ")
}
```

Here is TicTacToeModel:

```
class TicTacToeModel: ObservableObject {
var playerToMove : Bool = false // App breaks when set to @Published
}
```

Here's full source code: (also available at https://pastebin.com/srDNZHnU)

```
// ComponentView:
 
import SwiftUI
import Combine
 
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
    @ObservedObject var ticTacToe = TicTacToeModel()
    @State var selection : Bool = false
    @State var move : Bool = false
    @State var gameOver : Bool = false
    
    func buttonAction(_ index : Int) {
        if self.ticTacToe.makeMove(index: index, gameType: selection) {
            self.gameOver = self.ticTacToe.gameOver.1
        }
    }
    
    var currPlayer: String {
        print("runned", self.ticTacToe.playerToMove)
        return self.ticTacToe.playerToMove == false ? "X" : "O"
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Picker(selection: $selection, label: Text("Game")) {
                Text("AI").tag(false)
                Text("PVP").tag(true)
            }
            .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
            .padding(.horizontal, 89)
            .onReceive(Just(selection)) { _ in
                self.ticTacToe.resetGame()
            }
            
            Spacer()
            
            Text(self.selection == false ? "Tic Tac Toe - AI" : "Tic Tac Toe - PVP")
                .bold()
                .font(.title)
                //.padding(.bottom)
                .foregroundColor(colorScheme == .dark ? Color.white.opacity(0.7) : Color.black.opacity(0.7))
            
            Text(self.selection == true ? "\(currPlayer) to move" : " ")
                .bold()
                .font(.title2)
                .padding(.bottom)
                .foregroundColor(colorScheme == .dark ? Color.white.opacity(0.7) : Color.black.opacity(0.7))
            
            ForEach(0 ..< ticTacToe.squares.count / 3, id: \.self, content: { row in
                HStack {
                    ForEach(0 ..< 3, content: { column in
                        let index = row * 3 + column
                        SquareView(dataSouce: ticTacToe.squares[index], action: { self.buttonAction(index) })
                    })
                }
            })
            
            Spacer()
            
            Button(action: {
                self.ticTacToe.resetGame()
            }, label: {
                Text("Reset")
                    .foregroundColor(Color.red.opacity(0.7))
            })
        }.alert(isPresented: self.$gameOver, content: {
            Alert(title: Text("Game Over"),
                  message: Text(self.ticTacToe.gameOver.0 != .empty ?
                                self.ticTacToe.gameOver.0 == .x ? "You Won!" : "AI Won!" : "Draw!"),
                  dismissButton: Alert.Button.destructive(Text("Ok"), action: {
                self.ticTacToe.resetGame()
            }))
        })
    }
}
 
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
 
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------
// TicTacToe:
 
import Foundation
 
class TicTacToeModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var squares = [Square]()
    var playerToMove : Bool = false // App breaks when set to @Published
    
    init() {
        for _ in 0...8 {
            squares.append(Square(status: .empty))
        }
    }
    
    func resetGame() {
        for i in 0...8 {
            squares[i].squareStatus = .empty
            playerToMove = false
        }
    }
    
    var gameOver : (SquareStatus, Bool) {
        get {
            if winner != .empty {
                return (winner, true)
            } else {
                for i in 0...8 {
                    if squares[i].squareStatus == .empty {
                        return (.empty, false)
                    }
                }
                return (.empty, true)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func makeMove(index: Int, gameType: Bool) -> Bool {
        var player: SquareStatus
        if playerToMove == false {
            player = .x
        } else {
            player = .o
        }
        if squares[index].squareStatus == .empty {
            squares[index].squareStatus = player
            if playerToMove == false && gameType == false {
                moveAI()
                playerToMove = true
            }
            playerToMove.toggle()
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
    
    private func moveAI() {
        var index = Int.random(in: 0...8)
        playerToMove = true
        while makeMove(index: index, gameType: true) == false && gameOver.1 == false {
            index = Int.random(in: 0...8)
        }
    }
    
    private var winner: SquareStatus {
        get {
            if let check = self.checkIndexes([0, 1, 2]) {
                return check
            } else if let check = self.checkIndexes([3, 4, 5]) {
                return check
            } else if let check = self.checkIndexes([6, 7, 8]) {
                return check
            } else if let check = self.checkIndexes([0, 3, 6]) {
                return check
            } else if let check = self.checkIndexes([1, 4, 7]) {
                return check
            } else if let check = self.checkIndexes([2, 5, 8]) {
                return check
            } else if let check = self.checkIndexes([0, 4, 8]) {
                return check
            } else if let check = self.checkIndexes([2, 4, 6]) {
                return check
            }
            return .empty
        }
    }
    
    private func checkIndexes(_ indexes : [Int]) -> SquareStatus? {
        var xCount : Int = 0
        var oCount : Int = 0
        for index in indexes {
            let square = squares[index]
            if square.squareStatus == .x {
                xCount += 1
            } else if square.squareStatus == .o {
                oCount += 1
            }
        }
        if xCount == 3 {
            return .x
        } else if oCount == 3 {
            return .o
        }
        return nil
    }
}
 
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------
// SquareView:
 
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
 
enum SquareStatus {
    case empty
    case x
    case o
}
 
class Square : ObservableObject {
    @Published var squareStatus : SquareStatus
    
    init(status: SquareStatus) {
        self.squareStatus = status
    }
}
 
struct SquareView : View {
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
    @ObservedObject var dataSouce : Square
    var action: () -> Void
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.action()
        }, label: {
            Text(self.dataSouce.squareStatus == .x ?
                 "X" : self.dataSouce.squareStatus == .o ? "O" : " ")
            .font(.system(size: 60))
            .bold()
            .foregroundColor(colorScheme == .dark ? Color.white.opacity(0.9) : Color.black.opacity(0.9))
            .frame(width: 90, height: 90, alignment: .center)
            .background(colorScheme == .dark ? Color.white.opacity(0.3).cornerRadius(10) : Color.gray.opacity(0.3).cornerRadius(10))
            .padding(4)
        })
    }
}
```

I expected that "Next move" will work fine if I add `@Published` to that variable, but my code breaks with no errors. I tried creating new var with `@Published` for test, and it was working until in any function I set it to something different.

Comment: You’ll get a better response if your Minimal Reproducible Example is located in the question section as code. It will be tough to find someone that is willing to go to your pastebin for your example

Comment: I’ll add more info in the question soon. Ty for indicating that.

Comment: is it crashing on device or in preview? the code you provided is working on my machine... have you tried cleaning/deleting derived data/restarting?

Comment: I still had to go to your PasteBin to see the problem.  Even though it is a fairly large example, could you put your full code in place of the PasteBin link?  Stack Overflow Q&A should be standalone without required outside links.

Comment: In general, it is best to post a full working example in your question.  Ideally, it should be the *minimal* code to show the problem, so start paring down a copy of your code until you have something small to post.  In the process of doing that, you might just remove the code causing you the trouble, and you will then have discovered the source of your problem yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your `Picker`.  More specifically, the `.onReceive`.  It is activating anytime the view redraws which causes `self.ticTacToe.resetGame()` to run which updates `playerToMove` which triggers a view redraw ... and you have an infinite loop.

```
Picker(selection: $selection, label: Text("Game")) {
    Text("AI").tag(false)
    Text("PVP").tag(true)
}
.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
.padding(.horizontal, 89)
.onReceive(Just(selection)) { _ in
    self.ticTacToe.resetGame()
}
```

Change `.onReceive` to `onChange(of:)`:

```
.onChange(of: selection) { _ in
    self.ticTacToe.resetGame()
}
```

This will activate only when `selection` is actually changed.

---

**Note:**

You have:

```
@ObservedObject var ticTacToe = TicTacToeModel()
```

in your `ContentView`.  Since this is your model's source of truth, it should be:

```
@StateObject var ticTacToe = TicTacToeModel()
```

As a general rule of thumb, if you are assigning an initial value to the object then use `@StateObject`.  If the object gets its value passed in from the calling view, use `@ObservedObject`.

Comment: I will have a look tomorrow, thanks.